# Why do actions with class and public method don't fire __construct()

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

I'm trying to understand how WordPress works with actions, classes, and methods.

If there is a class "TestClass" and it has a public method 'method1'

The method can be hooked to any action as "add_action('theHook', ['TestClass', 'method1']);"

From my understanding. If you don't initialize the class, you can not access its public methods and objects. Now, I would assume that WordPress has to follow this, and it must initialize my "TestClass", which will cause for public __construct() to fire.

However, after testing this, it does not fire __construct()..

Why is this?. I know a fix would be to self initialize inside 'method1', but I'm trying to figure out why WordPress behaves this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because WordPress call your method as a static function: `TestClass::method()`

There is various solution:

### 1. Init class before add Action

Initialize your class before add action, like that:

```php
$test = new TestClass();
add_action('hook', [$test, 'method']);
```

### 2. Call hook inside your Class:

```php
class TestClass {
    public function __construct() {
        // Your construct
    }
    public function method() {
        // Your Method
    }

    public function call_hook() {
        add_action('hook', [$this, 'method']);
    }
}

$test = new TestClass();
$test->call_hook();
```

### 3. Use a singleton

And if you need to to have only one instance of your class and call it in various place, you have to take a look to [Singleton design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

#### Demonstration:

```php
class MySingletonClass {

    private static $__instance = null;
    private $count = 0;
    private function __construct() {
        // construct
    }

    public static function getInstance() {
        if (is_null(self::$__instance)) {
            self::$__instance = new MySingletonClass();
        }
        return self::$__instance;
    }

    public function method() {
        $this->count += 1;
        error_log("count:".$this->count);
    }
}

$singleton = MySingletonClass::getInstance();
add_action('wp_head', [$singleton, 'method']);


$singleton2 = MySingletonClass::getInstance();
add_action('wp_footer', [$singleton2, 'method']);
```